# Run ajaxed javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I know this has been covered a few times, but I'm completely a noob when it comes to javascript so I have no idea what I'm doing. I am running a javascript that sends variables to a php file and that info is ajaxed into the current page using innerhtml. Here is that part of the code...

```
function givingHistory(dyear,did)
    {
    var divname="giving" + dyear;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'finance/givinghistory.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            year: dyear,
            id: did
        },
        success: function(givedata) {
            document.getElementById(divname).innerHTML = givedata;
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

In the `givedata` function response from the php file there is a call to another javascript function that is already loaded in my common `.js` file (so both javascript functions are loaded when the page loads). How do I get the onClick that is added via innerhtml to work? Inside the php file, I check to see `if id = a php session variable`. If it does it spits out the text that includes the `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a specific id/class/identifier when the page loads in the $('***') function then the action will only bind to that. To get the action bind to anything ever try using `$(document).on('click', **selector**, function() {});`.

Previously there was bind/live that bound to elements as and when but `on` is the function now.

Also why are you mixing the $.ajax (jQuery) with document.getElementById(divname).innerHTML (regular javascript)? If you are already using jQuery you could just use `$('#'+divname).html(blahbahblah);`